# Different delimiters in javascript toString()

Tags: javascript, tostring

I have :

```js
var myArray = [{
  'zero': '1'
}, {
  'two': '2'
}, {
  'three': '3'
}];
var result = myArray.toString();
console.log(result);
```

And it returns the output like this `zero,1,two,2,three,3.`

I want

```
zero:1,two:2,three:3
```

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: `myArray.map(v => JSON.stringify(v)).join(',');` or something

Comment: Due to JSON format why dont you try `JSON.stringify(myArray )` instead of `myArray .toString();`

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate the object's entries and join them.

```js
var array = [ {'zero':'1'}, {'two':'2'}, {'three':'3'}],
    result = array.map(o => Object.entries(o).map(a => a.join(':'))).toString();
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

if key or value doesn't include '{','}','[',']' in it

```js
var myArray = [ {'zero':'1'}, {'two':'2'}, {'three':'3'}];
var result = JSON.stringify( myArray )
result = result.replace(/[{\[\]}]/g,'').replace(/["']/g, "")
console.log( result )
```

Else you can try this,

```js
var myArray = [ {'ze{ro':'1'}, {'two':'2'},{'thre]e':'3'}];

var result = ''
myArray.forEach( data => {
Object.keys( data ).forEach( key => {
  result = result + key + ':' + data[ key ] + ','
})
})
result = result.substring( 0 , result.length - 1 )
console.log( result )
```

Comment: What if one of the keys or values is a string that contains `{`?

Comment: @Barmar, yes if one of the keys or values contain { then it will not work.